# Calculating correlation between 3 variables in R

Tags: r, igraph, correlation

I am new to R and could use some help trying to compute the correlation between three variables. What I am trying to do is see if there is a correlation between the well being score index and the weight(number of people) moving from one state to the next. The "from" column is the state that the people are moving from and the "to" column is where they are moving to. Weight is the number of people that moved from that state to the new one. I need to calculate if there is a correlation between where people are moving from and the well being index score of the "to" state that there are moving to. I hope that made sense but if there are any questions I can try explain more. I have look through some online forums and can't find a problem similar to mine and need help with the coding part.

Here is the links structure:

```
structure(list(from = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"), to = c("Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut"), weight = c(423L, 894L, 2057L, 3045L, 2328L, 1102L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the nodes structure:

```
structure(list(State = c("Hawaii", "Alaska", "South Dakota", "Maine", "Colorado", "Vermont"), Well.Being.Score = c(65.2, 64, 63.7, 63.6, 63.5, 63.5), Social.Rank = c(46L, 1L, 29L, 18L, 21L, 5L), Financial.Rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 19L, 39L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @G5W Sorry, I fixed it now.

Comment: Is plotting part of the question? It's very different from computing correlations and also we have too little data to reproduce the mess.

Comment: @JuliusVainora The plotting is a side tangent. The computing correlations is what I need help with the most. What can I provide to help? The links data file is about 2,500 rows long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there are several pairs of variables whose correlation coefficients are of interest here. In particular:

- weight vs. well-being (WB) of "to" states,
- weight vs. WB of "from" states,
- WB of "to" vs. "from",
- weight vs. (WB of "to" - WB of "from").

So we may start by doing a double merge

```
m <- merge(merge(links, nodes, by.x = "to", by.y = "State"), 
           nodes, by.x = "from", by.y = "State", suff = c(".to", ".from"))
```

where now we have all the variables of interest in the same place, and

```
with(m, cor(cbind(weight, WB.from = Well.Being.Score.from, 
                  WB.to = Well.Being.Score.to,
                  WB.diff = Well.Being.Score.to - Well.Being.Score.from)))
```

should return an interesting correlation matrix (no output here as there's too little data available).

Comment: That helps out a lot, thank you for taking the time. If I am trying to plot the graph of the network with all the ties between the states being the number of people moving to and from, would you know a good approach? When I go to plot it, a lot of nodes overlap and the ties are hard to see.

Comment: @RyanPorter, other than looking into `?layout` and different options there, only some straightforward ideas come to mind, like reducing text and node sizes, increasing plot area. I also see that there are quite a few similar questions on SO, perhaps those will helps.